# How can I fix 'Missing system type and architecture' error when downloading FFmpeg library in Maui.net?

Tags: c#, android, ios, ffmpeg, maui

Missing system type and architecture when Xabe.FFmpeg.Downloader.FFmpegDownloader.GetLatestVersion in Maui.net

I was trying to run the FFmpeg library download code and I always get this error

Missing system type and architecture

Steps to replicate the problem

Create a new Maui project

Install NuGet Xabe.FFmpeg.Downloader

This is the homepage code

```
namespace MauiApp1;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    // A button to download FFmpeg
    private Button Button;

    public MainPage()
    {
        Button = new() { Text = "Download FFmpeg" };

        Button.Clicked += Button_Clicked;

        Content = new StackLayout()
        {
            Children =
            {
                Button
            }
        };
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
            }

            status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
            }

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {

                await Xabe.FFmpeg.Downloader.FFmpegDownloader.GetLatestVersion(Xabe.FFmpeg.Downloader.FFmpegVersion.Official);
                //await Xabe.FFmpeg.Downloader.FFmpegDownloader.GetLatestVersion(Xabe.FFmpeg.Downloader.FFmpegVersion.Android);
                //await Xabe.FFmpeg.Downloader.FFmpegDownloader.GetLatestVersion(Xabe.FFmpeg.Downloader.FFmpegVersion.Official, Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "FFmpeg"));
                //await Xabe.FFmpeg.Downloader.FFmpegDownloader.GetLatestVersion(Xabe.FFmpeg.Downloader.FFmpegVersion.Android, Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "FFmpeg"));


                await DisplayAlert("Install", "Install completed successfully", "OK");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Show an alert message with exception message 
            await DisplayAlert("Install Failed", $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}", "OK");
        }
    }
}
```

These are file access permissions on Android

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Have you contacted the author of the library?  Are you sure MAUI is a supported platform?

Comment: I will try to communicate with the author of the library, thank you

Comment: https://github.com/tomaszzmuda/Xabe.FFmpeg/blob/7af0345089bec7a6c5ecdcb339dd6e01e36b96cd/src/Xabe.FFmpeg.Downloader/OperatinSystemProvider/OperatingSystemProvider.cs#L7 as you can see from their source code only Windows/MacOS/Linux supported.

Comment: But here are the values of the variable that determines the operating system on which the binary library will be downloaded
https://github.com/tomaszzmuda/Xabe.FFmpeg/blob/7af0345089bec7a6c5ecdcb339dd6e01e36b96cd/src/Xabe.FFmpeg.Downloader/FFmpegDownloader.cs

And you can see the type variable in the code that I showed and it holds the value android

Comment: Sounds like they prepared the type variable to include android, but have not implemented that one.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am encountering the same issue and opened an issue at the github project: https://github.com/tomaszzmuda/Xabe.FFmpeg/issues/471